# PyTorch model not releasing peak memory after computation

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, pytorch, sentence-transformers

I am using [SentenceTransformers](https://www.sbert.net/) library to get a text embedding of a given text. I do inference on one of the pre-trained models from the library, and use the embedding vector for further computations.
When the model is doing inference, there is a spike in memory usage, as expected. However, after I get the embedding that I want, the memory usage does not go down.

I am profiling the memory with the following code -

```
from time import sleep

import torch
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

@profile
def encode_text(text):

    text_encoder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-albert-small-v2')
    embedding = text_encoder.encode(text)

    return embedding

encode_text(['This is a sentance'])
sleep(3)
```

I am profiling with [memory-profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) by running `mprof run --python python main.py`.
This gives the following memory profile (running `mprof plot`) -

[image]

The memory gradually increases from when the function is called to when it finishes (the blue square brackets). However, after that, the memory is never released. This does not make sense to me since once I have the `embedding` vector, there is nothing in the code that should need to continue using up that much memory.

I tried wrapping everything in `torch.no_grad()`, setting `text_encoder.requires_grad_(False)` and `text_encoder.eval()` after creating `text_encoder`. I also tried doing `del text_encoder` after running inference.

None of this seems to make a difference.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how do I can free up this memory?

I am running the following versions of the libraries on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

```
torch 1.13.0+cu117 
sentence_transformers 2.2.2
```